# How to use database in SQL Server instead App_Data folder on Model Binding in webforms

Tags: sql-server, webforms, model-binding

I followed this tutorial on model Binding for ASP.NET and it creates the database in App_Data Folder as .mdf file. There is nothing explaining how to change the database destiny in the tutorial and I can't find anything as good as this for webforms.

[Tutorial :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data)

The database is created when i type in packet manager console this command

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName ContosoUniversityModelBinding.Models.SchoolContext
```

Nothing appears on my SQL server instance of this file and I would like to know how can i change this so it creates or uses a database on my SQL-Server instance? I'm really enjoying this new tool to make data management in webforms, if someone can point me in the right direction i'll appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours i figured it out. You can make a constructor for your DataContext class to accept a connection string from your webconfig. It will use that. In case someone has same problem, just do this on your DC class

```
public class Requisicoes : DbContext
{
    public Requisicoes()
        : base("name=Res_cnString")
    {

    }
}
```

where the name=Res_cnString is your connection string name in web config;